# Cgridview export csv using extension

Tags: php, csv, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

I've implemented the wrapper extension for for eexcelview here:http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/toexcel/ to export my cgridview data. However, at this very time, I can only figure out how to export all the records for an entire model.

This is my action in the model's controller

```
    public function actionExcel()
{
    $fileName = 'Packaging_Metric_Data_Export_'. date("m-d-y");
    // Load data (scoped)
    $model = PackagingMetric::model()->findAll();;


        // Export it
    $this->toExcel($model,
        array(
        //'id',
        'date',
        'room',
        'lot',
        'country',
        'total_labor_hours',
        'total_run_time',
        'std_rate',
        ),
        $fileName,
        array(
            'creator' => 'Data Access Portal',
        ),
        'Excel2007'
    );
}
```

The comments on the page for the extension explain to use a method similar to this to achieve this feature. However, I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
$model = YourModel('search');
$model->type = 1; // This will filter out all the results whose type is 1 
$dataProvider = $model->search();
```

Could anyone clarify how to retrieve the filtered cgridview results to be exported by the extension?

Comment: You should be able to specify a condition in [findAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail)

Comment: could you clarify? How do I retrieve the active data in cgridview as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this module, but it looks like you're not looking for [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView), but a [dataprovider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/IDataProvider) of some sort.

That being said, in your code above, you have:

```
    $model = PackagingMetric::model()->findAll(); //removed extra ;
```

I'm not sure what PackagingMetric is, but it looks like it's extending CActiveRecord, and contains a [findAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) method, so you should be able to make that line something like:

```
$condition = 'lot = 1';
$model = PackagingMetric::model()->findAll($condition);
```

Comment: this should allow me to find things I specify directly in the controoler, however I am still confused as to how I can call the active "search" data from cgridview as a parameter

Comment: If you already have data displayed in a cgridview, just pass that instead of $model when calling toExcel()

Comment: can this data be called using a POST call? If so can you exemplify